# Hyperlinked citation aliases for biblatex

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

Some time ago I made the (happy) switch from `natbib` to `biblatex`. However, one of the things that are not working as I expected are citation aliases, which in natbib allowed me to specify the text I wanted to display for specific citations. This would

1. add the item to the bibliography;
2. display the specified alias instead of the item's citation;
3. make the printed alias a link to the corresponding entry in the bibliography.
4. And since this is biblatex, I would like them to also add the appropriate backref if the `backref` option is used.

I've tried using the `natbib=true` option when loading `biblatex` (as stated in section 3.7.9 of the documentation), but this does not solve problem **3**.

To try my hand at solving **3** I made an attempt exemplified in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,backref=true]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2013},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Some Journal},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pgfkeys{
  /bibalias/.is family, bibalias,
  text/.store in = \bibaliastext,
}
\newcommand{\defcitealias}[2]{%
  \pgfkeys{
    bibalias,
    #1/.style={text={#2}},
  }
}
\newcommand{\citealias}[1]{%
  \pgfkeys{bibalias, #1}%
  \nocite{#1}%
%   \bibhyperref[#1]{\bibaliastext}%
}
\defcitealias{test}{an alias}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

This is a test for \citealias{test}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

But it seems `\bibhyperref` does not work as I expected, since this stops with an `Undefined control sequence` error, and after reading the documentation more carefully, it seems it is only available during citation style definitions. It also has the problem that `\nocite` does not add backreferences to the bibliography (**4**).

So, how can use citation aliases in biblatex, hopefully fulfilling all four criteria stated above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to go about with this, you can either use the `shorthand` field, or employ the `natbib` compatibility mode. The difference between the two approaches is that with the former (the `shorthand` option) the alias (`shorthand`) is used almost exclusively throughout the document as citation label, while the latter (`natbib` aliasing) solution allows to choose between using the alias or the standard citation label by choosing between `\cite` and `\citealias` (or `\citep` and `\citepalias`).

---

The field `shorthand` defines a new label for the entry that is to be used instead of the "standard" label the style would normally generate ([see §2.2.2, p. 22 of the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

```
@article{test,
  author  = {Author, A.},
  year    = {2013},
  title   = {Title},
  journal = {Some Journal},
}
```

Would in an `authoryear` style probably be cited as "Author 2013", if we add the `shorthand` field

```
@article{test,
  author  = {Author, A.},
  year    = {2013},
  title   = {Title},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  shorthand = {alias},
}
```

the citation will be "alias".

Some styles take to introduce a shorthand (for example, the `verbose` styles cite the full entry (the first time) and add a "henceforth cited as *`shorthand`*" message, subsequent citations will then use the shorthand).

If you use shorthands in a non-`verbose` style (or one that does not introduce the shorthands), it is a good idea to also `\printshorthands` ([see §3.6.3, pp. 73 sq. of the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf))

Hyper-linking, of course, works as expected here; so does the `backref` functionality.

---

`biblatex`'s `natbib` compatibility mode should - with a few modifications - do exactly what you want.

1) and 2) are easily satisfied by `natbib=true`.

3) To add links to the bibliography entry add this to your preamble (you can find the original definition in `blx-natbib.def`).

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetalias}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\@citealias{\thefield{entrykey}}}}%<-- added \printtext[bibhyperref]{...}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citepalias}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\@citealias{\thefield{entrykey}}}}%<-- added \printtext[bibhyperref]{...}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother
```

4) Of course, a `\nocite`d item will not have a backreference in the bibliography, it was not technically cited after all.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,backref=true,natbib]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2013},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Some Journal},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetalias}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\@citealias{\thefield{entrykey}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citepalias}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\@citealias{\thefield{entrykey}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother

\defcitealias{test}{an alias}

\begin{document}
This is a test for \citetalias{test} and \citepalias{test}; the standard cite commands give \citet{test} and \citep{test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

One can easily check that a simple `\citetalias{test}` is sufficient to create a backreference.

Comment: I agree that using `biblatex`' `\DeclareCiteCommand` is the way to go, but the output of your aliases are not correct based on the `\defcitealias` definition.

Comment: Well, the fact that your response extended beyond your first paragraph sort of proves that the `natbib` compatibility mode does _not_ do everything I wanted: i actually said that I tried it and was not satisfied. Apart from that, as @jon said, this answer seems to have a problem with the aliases, but it definitely looks like its headed in the right direction.

Comment: @jja I missed the `@` in the code and therefore did not enclose it in `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`, so the alias was not printed correctly. Does the code do what you want now? I hope you also approve of the reworded first paragraph.

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted. I see some in-depth reading of the `biblatex` documentation in my future!

Comment: The `shorthand` field is the correct answer! Maybe this can be made more prominent? I only noticed it now...

Comment: I had upvoted it, but had not realised I had yet to accept it. Sorry about that!

Comment: @jja No worries! I just thought since you mentioned that `shorthand` is the correct answer, you might as well accept it.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Usually bold entry keys with `biblatex` mean that something went wrong and couldn't be found (there should be a corresponding warning in the `.log`). I just compiled the MWE with pdfLaTeX, Biber, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX though and got the expected output (in particular no bold and no warnings), so presumably something else is up at your end. If you need help, I suggest you ask a new question explaining exactly what you are trying to do and how it does not work for you.

Comment: @moewe Yes thanks, in-between I realized I had deleted the `\defcitealias{}` line!...